# can some one please explain this line of codings from scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am really struggling a lot to understand this line of code. can someone please explain in detail?

```
def sequence[A](aos: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] =
  aos.foldRight[Option[List[A]]](Some(Nil))((a,acc) => map2(a,acc)(_ :: _))
```

Comment: What about this line do you already understand?  What specifically do you need help with?  Do you have any ideas to what it might mean at all?

Comment: yes i just do not understand the [Option[List[A]]] after foldRight... What does that mean? do we need to pass the return type in it? @puhlen

Comment: what is `map2`?

Comment: @Rumoku `map2` is probably coming from the applicative functor on `Option`. It should have the following signature: `def map2[A, B, Z](fa: Option[A], fb: Option[B])(f: (A, B) => Z): Option[Z]`, what it does is: it applies the given function to the values in the two options if both of them are present.

Comment: Map2 is a function which combines two Options and returns a third one
**def map2[A,B,C] (ao: Option[A], bo: Option[B]) (f: (A,B) => C) :Option[C] =    ao.flatMap(aa=>
      bo.map(bb =>
        f(aa,bb)))**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to explain with only a small piece of code, but I'll give it a try.

**Explanation:** That function is trying to implement a `sequence` operation on `List[Option[A]]`. This operation is really common in FP (I recommend you look at a general implementation found in [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/cc4080c86b07bd202b83b5fce81429d1c516b931/core/src/main/scala/cats/Traverse.scala#L65). In general it converts type `F[G[A]]` to `G[F[A]]`, in your example it specifically converts `List[Option[A]]` to a `Option[List[A]]`.

**Update:** You have to specify `Option[List[A]]` to make sure the compiler will infer the correct type. Due to how ADTs are implemented in Scala, if you don't specify the return type the compiler will infer `Some[List[Nothing]]` as your return type.